# VBA - Convert string into Arithmetic Operator

Tags: vba, excel

Using VBA, I am trying to convert a string such as "/10" into an arithmetic operation, so that if I somehow connect it (depending on how it gets converted)  after the number 200, the number 20 would be returned.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `Application.Evaluate(23 & "/10")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a Math Parser. Look around for a library that you can use in VBA. If you're working in excel specific stuff - I'm sure excel already has a math parser built in - though I have no idea how you can gain access to it as the programmer. Maybe stick the expression in a cell as a string and call Eval().

**EDIT**
Microsoft intentionally removed this feature from function calls in excel, however it can be reinstated by creating the following function:

```
Function Eval(Ref As String)
Application.Volatile
Eval = Evaluate(Ref)
End Function
```

Then just call `Eval("200" & "/10")`

**EDIT2**

As noted in the comments below, modern versions of VBA support

```
Application.Evaluate("200" & "/10")
```

Comment: +1 for good explanation, but I think `Application.Evaluate` is probably a better solution.

Comment: Thank you. Evaluate skipped my mind. I can just use: Evaluate("200" & "/10")

Comment: Probably is better, @DavidZemens. I haven't touched VBA in a long time  so just went with whatever google turned up first.

Comment: No worries! Actually now that I look at your initial answer, you're using `Application.Evaluate` anyways, just putting it inside another function. This would be usable on the worksheet, which might be handy!

Answer (score 1):

the below example provides a way of accomplishing what you are looking for.

```
Dim s As String
s = "/10"
Dim i As Integer
i = 200
Dim v
v = Evaluate(CStr(i) & s)
MsgBox v
```